# ng-click not triggering function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<button ng-click="overlayShow('#overlay-exceptions')"
        class="ds-button ds-primary">
    <div class="ds-align-text-center">SUBMIT NEW REQUEST</div>
</button>
```

```
// To open overlays and correctly handles the background page
$rootScope.overlayShow = function(id) {
    id = $(id);
    console.log(id)
    var list = $rootScope.openOverlays;

    if(list.length == 0) $('#gsi-html').addClass('gsi-no-scroll');
    if(list.indexOf(id) < 0) {
        list.push(id);
        id.addClass('ds-open');
    }
}
```

ng-click button is not triggering the function. Any ideas on how to get this resolved, I'm thinking it may be a syntax error.

Comment: Any error/warning on the browser console?

Comment: Yea, any errors? Also, are you sure you are bootstrapping your app right? Do other things work as expected?

Comment: No errors warnings on the browser console,

Comment: Also, it the first piece I'm adding with actual functionality. I have data pulling from a database and that's working properly.